# On what network do the clients connect to the CEPH cluster (public/private)?

Tags: ceph

It's recommended to have a public network and cluster network when setting up CEPH.

For what I understand this cluster network is what the nodes use to replicate data accross so that would preferably be a 10 gigabit network.

However I read that only the monitor nodes need to be on the public network too.
Does that mean that the clients, in my case a Proxmox cluster, connect on the monitor node? That would mean that all the data goes through those nodes, and so that public network would also preferably be 10 gigabit?

Answer (score 1):

To separate traffic use CEPH synchronization on the private network (10 GB/s NIC). For the monitor and clients, you can use the public network. As for throughput for the public network, it always depends on your performance requirements (use 10GB/s NIC to achieve maximum performance) http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rados/configuration/network-config-ref/